# Control is not passing to newly opened page in selenium-java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have two web pages and hence two seperate classes. In first class, I am performing action on first page by clicking a link which loads new page in the same tab.

```
    FirstClass {
    Driver.click();
    }


    SecondClass extends FirstClass {
    //code goes here
    }
```

Then in the second class, I am inheriting the first class by using extend. But when I perform action on elements of 2nd page its throws no such element exception.

If I perform the actions in the first class itself after clicking on the link, everything related to second page works fine. But when I create second class and try to perform the action, I get no such element error.

If I am correct,then the problem is not with switching windows. I tried with switching the control too. but it is not working.

Please let me know what is the problem and solution. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code for First Class:

```
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Set;

 import org.testng.Assert;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 import pom.AllJobsPage;
 import pom.DashboardPage;
 import pom.ResponseManagerPage;
 import pom.SessionPage;

 public class TestSession extends ClickLogin{

@Test
public void testSession() throws InterruptedException
{
    SessionPage s=new SessionPage(driver);
    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
    s.SessionSubmit();
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        DashboardPage db=new DashboardPage(driver);
        String winHandleDashB = driver.getWindowHandle();
        db.ClickViewMore();
         Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for(String curWindow : allWindows){
            driver.switchTo().window(curWindow);
        }
        AllJobsPage Aj=new AllJobsPage(driver);
        Aj.ClickResponseLink();
```

Code for second class is:

```
package scripts;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pom.ResponseManagerPage;

public class TestResponseManager extends TestSession {

@Test
public void TestResponseManagerPage() throws NoSuchElementException, InterruptedException
{
    ResponseManagerPage p=new ResponseManagerPage(driver);
    p.GetStatus();
    Set<String> JobWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String curWindow : JobWindows) 
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(curWindow);
    }
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().equals(title));
}
```

}

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code of both the classes and your error stack trace.

Comment: I have updated the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
string BaseWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = driver.WindowHandles;
if(handles.Count == 2)
       {
            foreach (string handle in handles)
            {
                if (handle != BaseWindow)
                {
                   //Do Something.
                }
            }
       }
driver.SwitchTo().Window(BaseWindow);
```

This worked for me. Code is in C#. Hope this might be helpful.